# Stack smashing detected (Aborted Core Dump)

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings

My code is supposed to replicate the `strncat()` function. The code gives the desired output but it always ends up with the "stack smashing detected" error. I'd like to know why and how to fix it.

What am I doing wrong or not doing at all?

main.h

```
#ifndef MAIN_H
#define MAIN_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int _putchar(char c);
char *_strcat(char *dest, char *src);
char *_strncat(char *dest, char *src, int n);

#endif
```

1-main.c

```
#include "main.h"
#include <stdio.h>

/**
 * main - check the code
 *
 * Return: Always 0.
 */

int main(void)
{
        char s1[98] = "Hello ";
        char s2[] = "World!\n";
        char *ptr;

        printf("%s\n", s1);
        printf("%s", s2);
        ptr = _strncat(s1, s2, 1);
        printf("%s\n", s1);
        printf("%s", s2);
        printf("%s\n", ptr);
        ptr = _strncat(s1, s2, 1024);
        printf("%s", s1);
        printf("%s", s2);
        printf("%s", ptr);
        return (0);
}
```

And this is the code for the custom version of the `strncat()`function.

1-strncat.c

```
#include "main.h"

/**
 * _strncat - Concatenates strings
 * @dest: destination string
 * @src: source string
 * @n: Max bytes
 * Return: dest
 */

char *_strncat(char *dest, char *src, int n)
{
        int srclen = 0;
        int destlen = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        while (src[srclen] != '\0')
        {
                srclen++;
        }
        while (dest[destlen] != '\0')
        {
                destlen++;
        }
        for (i = destlen; (i < (destlen + n) && j < n); i++)
        {
                dest[i] = src[j];
                j++;
        }
        dest[destlen + n] = '\0';
        return (dest);
}
```

[image]

Comment: 1024 is bigger than 98

Comment: Hint: Shouldn't the loop use `srclen`

Comment: In `ptr = _strncat(s1, s2, 1024)`, `dest[destlen + n] = '\0'` will write to `s1[7+1024]`, which is out of bounds. `s1` is on the stack, hence the message.

Comment: I guess I need to find a way to limit s2 till it reaches '\0' rather than the entire 1024 in ```ptr = _strncat(s1, s2, 1024)```  How can I do that?

Comment: @SupportUkraine Could you please be more elaborate?

Comment: @AkintolaOluwaseyiAlex This `(i < (destlen + n) && j < n)` makes little sense as both sides of the `&&` checks for the same thing (i.e. max `n` chars).... Would `(i < (destlen + n) && j < srclen)` make more sense? And for `dest[destlen + n] = '\0'` see the comment from Ruud H.

Comment: @SupportUkraine, j < srclen did make more sense. j increments till it gets to the value of the length of s2 and the expression becomes false, and the concatenation loop exits. Stack smack error resolved! Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function (correctly) determines the value of `srclen` but then never uses it … but it *should* use it.

That value should be the 'limit' for the `j` variable in the `for` loop, because that `j` is used as the index in the `src` string. Your use of `j < n` is thus wrong – the `n` limit is taken care of by the other test, `i < (destlen + n)`.

Also, the `dest[destlen + n] = '\0';` line is wrong, because it does not take into consideration how many characters have *actually* been copied. That line, occurring **immediately after** the `for` loop has finished, can be simply `dest[i] = '\0';`, using what will be the correct `i` value.

Here is a working version of your function:

```c
char* _strncat(char* dest, const char* src, int n)
{
    int srclen = 0;
    int destlen = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    while (src[srclen] != '\0') {
        srclen++;
    }
    while (dest[destlen] != '\0') {
        destlen++;
    }

    for (i = destlen; i < (destlen + n) && j < srclen; i++) {
        dest[i] = src[j];
        j++;
    }
    dest[i] = '\0'; // At loop exit, "i" will point to where the nul needs to be added.

    return dest;
}
```

Note that I've also added the `const` qualifier to the `src` parameter; this is not actually necessary but keeps your function's signature consistent with the standard `strncat`.

Comment: Note that, as pointed out in [John's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75605195/10871073), your shown code has a number of other issues. But the fixed `_strncat` function above will also 'suitably' mimic the standard `strncat` in that: *The behavior is undefined if the destination array does not have enough space for the contents of both dest and the first count characters of src, plus the terminating null character.*

Answer (score 1):

Preliminarily, your `_strncat()` computes the length of the source string, `srclen`, but never uses it.  That is not responsible for the crash however.

The point of passing a size to `strncat()` is to limit the number of bytes that may be copied from the source to the destination.  This serves at least three purposes:

- to allow for copying only a prefix of the source, and in particular
- to allow for copying from a source that is not null terminated, but also
- to prevent overflowing the destination.

The last of those relies on the caller to pass a number that accounts for the size of the destination array and the length of the string it currently contains.  By analogy, **this combination ...**

> ```
>         char s1[98] = "Hello ";
>
> ...
>
>         ptr = _strncat(s1, s2, 1024);
> ```

**... is abusive**, because the destination cannot accommodate as many additional bytes as is specified.  It could not do so even if it were initially empty.

Additionally, your implementation of `_strncat()` exacerbates that usage issue because **it does not stop copying when it reaches the end of the source string**.  It attempts to copy the full number of bytes regardless of what they are, and appends a string terminator after that.  That has the result that using a short source string does not protect from the ill effects of specifying an excessive length.

Other issues include:

- your `_strncat()` does not have the same signature as `strncat`, so
- it cannot handle `const` source strings, and
- it uses a less appropriate type for representing object sizes (`size_t` is preferred).  Also,
- it introduces and uses a lot of variables for its fairly simple function

This is how *I* would write the function (supposing that I could not rely on any standard library functions):

```
char *_strncat(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n) {
    char *dest_end = dest;

    // advance dest_end to point to the terminator of the destination string
    while (*dest_end) {
        dest_end++;
    }

    // copy from source to destination until either n bytes have been copied
    // or a string terminator is reached
    while (n-- && *src) {
        *dest_end++ = *src++;
    }

    // append a string terminator to the destination
    *dest_end = '\0';

    return dest;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have adjusted my for loop to ```for (i = destlen; (i < (destlen + n) && j < srclen); i++)```.   ```j < srclen``` makes sure I don't exceed the length of the source string regardless of the specified number of bytes n.

Comment: That will help, @AkintolaOluwaseyiAlex, but it does not by itself address the "appends a string terminator after that" part, because in the original code, the position where that terminator is written depends only on `n`, not on the source length.  Personally, I would structure things a bit differently: instead of precomputing `srclen`, I would fold that into the copying loop.  Break from the loop before copying a full `n` bytes if the next source byte is a terminator, and after the loop, add a terminator after the last byte actually written to the destination.